# Consulta SQL Server Mostrar Entrada y Salida por Empleado

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql

Hola que tal tengo una consulta en SQL Server donde quiero obtener Entrada y Salida de cada empleado pero al sacar con Max y Min no lo hace no entiendo porque

```
SELECT EMPLEADO.EMPNUMEMP
      ,Bitacora.Bitfecha as Fecha
      ,MAX(Bitacora.Bitfecha) as HoraEntrada
      ,MIN(Bitacora.Bitfecha) as HoraSalida
FROM Bitacora 
INNER JOIN Empleado on bitacora.Bitempnum = EMPLEADO.EMPNUMINT
WHERE format(Bitacora.Bitfecha,'dd/MM/yyyy') between '03/04/2019' and '03/04/2019'  
GROUP BY EMPLEADO.EMPNUMEMP, Bitacora.Bitfecha
ORDER BY EMPNUMEMP
```

Esto es lo que muestra pero ni siquiera lo agrupa por numero de empleado, alguna sugerencia por favor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes que agrupar por la fecha formateada tambien:
`GROUP BY EMPLEADO.EMPNUMEMP, format(Bitacora.Bitfecha,'dd/MM/yyyy')`

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, no sabia que tenia que poner la fecha formateada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te hace falta tratar, para efectos de agrupación y filtrado, la BitFecha solamente como fecha.

La manera más eficiente de hacerlo es aplicándole un molde de tipo a `date`, que no tiene hora.

Algo como:

```
SELECT   EMPLEADO.EMPNUMEMP
       , cast(Bitacora.Bitfecha as date) as Fecha
       , MAX(Bitacora.Bitfecha) as HoraEntrada
       , MIN(Bitacora.Bitfecha) as HoraSalida
  FROM Bitacora 
       INNER JOIN Empleado on bitacora.Bitempnum = EMPLEADO.EMPNUMINT
 WHERE cast(Bitacora.Bitfecha, as date) between '20190403' and '20190403'  
 GROUP BY EMPLEADO.EMPNUMEMP, cast(Bitacora.Bitfecha as date)
 ORDER BY EMPNUMEMP
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta me ayudo bastante.

Answer (score 0):

Tu consulta tiene varios problemas, el primero es que debes agrupar Bitacora.Bitfecha as Fecha como fecha sin tiempo. Segundo en tu Where, si deseas obtener una sola fecha no es necesario hacer el Between. Tu consulta quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
        SELECT EMPLEADO.EMPNUMEMP
              ,DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0,Bitacora.Bitfecha))  as Fecha -- Obtener fecha sin tiempo
              ,MAX(Bitacora.Bitfecha) as HoraEntrada
              ,MIN(Bitacora.Bitfecha) as HoraSalida
        FROM Bitacora 
        INNER JOIN Empleado on bitacora.Bitempnum = EMPLEADO.EMPNUMINT
        WHERE 
        DAY(Bitacora.Bitfecha) = 3 AND MONTH(Bitacora.Bitfecha) = 4 AND YEAR(Bitacora.Bitfecha) = 2019 -- Haces el WHERE especificando un día del año

        GROUP 
        EMPLEADO.EMPNUMEMP, 
        DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0,Bitacora.Bitfecha)) -- Agrupar fecha sin tiempo
        ORDER BY EMPNUMEMP
```

Espero te sea de utilidad

Comment: Muchas gracias me ayudo tu respuesta, de hecho si necesitaba hacer between para ocupar un rango de fechas solo que puse esa fecha como ejemplo, muchas gracias